# How to remove/hide the predictive autocomplete popup when I type in the tag/term metabox

Tags: metabox, tags, terms

When I start to type in a few letters in the tag or term metabox (in the post edit page) there is a predictive autocomplete popup thingy containing other tags/terms to choose from. How do I disable/hide this?

Comment: I want it hidden because I want each post to have a different term and therefore I don't want the author to choose a term that has already been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no filter or way to stop those Ajax calls. However, you can alter the response of Ajax call by using filter `term_search_min_chars`.

Which is actually to customize minimum number of characters after that Ajax will print the response. So we can make it `0` to never print the response!

```
/**
 * Remove tag search suggestions
 * @param int $tax The minimum number of characters required. Default 2.
 * @return int
 */
function remove_tag_suggestions($tax) {
    //You can place your condition if you want!
    return 0;
}
add_filter('term_search_min_chars', 'remove_tag_suggestions');
```

PS: I am not sure why do you want to remove this wonderful feature!

Comment: The way to go but note you can always filter ajax calls client-side with various jQuery functions, eg `$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) { if (options.url.indexOf('action=ajax-tag-search') !== -1) jqXHR.abort(); });`... (removing the `keydown` event handler on the tag input box would also work).